# PHP Date Function Decrease & days in date not working

Tags: php, date, strtotime

This is My PHP code. To decrease 7 days into date.

```
 $eventstart = '2014-06-29';
 $eventstart_time = strtotime('-7 day',strtotime($eventstart));
 echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($eventstart_time));
```

Output is.

```
5200-06-23
```

Second date.

```
 $eventstart = '2014-07-14';
 $eventstart_time = strtotime('-7 day',strtotime($eventstart));
 echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($eventstart_time));
```

Output is.

```
1970-01-01
```

Please Help How to Decrease 7 days into date.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to call `strtotime()` once. You can modify the date *before* you convert it to a Unix Timestamp:

```
$eventstart = '2014-07-14';
$eventstart_time = strtotime($eventstart . ' -7 day');
echo date("Y-m-d",$eventstart_time);
```

You can also use `DateTime()`

```
$eventstart = '2014-07-14';
$date = (new DateTime($eventstart))->modify('-7 days');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: ...right down to `5.2.17` --- +1 on both counts ;-)